# Inheritance and the new keyword

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, overriding, new-operator

when I add the new keyword or I remove things behave the same way ! new keyword is supposed to reimplement the method of the base class and hide it, here's the example :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();

            Console.WriteLine("bc __________________");
            bc.Method1();
            bc.Method2();
            Console.WriteLine("dc __________________");
            dc.Method1();
            dc.Method2();
            Console.WriteLine("bcdc __________________");
            bcdc.Method1();
            bcdc.Method2();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class BaseClass
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");
        }
        public void Method2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base - Method2");
        }
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");
        }
        public void Method2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method2");
        }
    }
```

the output of bcdc will show 
Base - Method1 
when calling bcdc.Method1(); isn't it supposed to show "Derived - Method1", if it's not the case, please explain to me why. (When using Virtual/override it works fine and I'm satisfied) but with the new keyword it works like with it or without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some ways `new` and `virtual/override` are opposite keywords.

- `virtual / override`: used to declare a single method with a single implementation across a range of types in an inheritance hierarchy
- `new`: used to **explicitly** declare a new method separate from all other methods with the same signature.  Not having `new` has the same effect it's just implicit

In this case the code has no `virtual` methods and hence the compiler is statically binding to the method dictated by the type of the reference on which it is invoked

Comment: If I understand your second point, the new keyword has no effect whether it's present or not, am I right? if yes, why does it exist ? if not please explain to me, and give me an example where new works just as override and makes the method1 of the derived class called

Comment: @AymenDaoudi the `new` keyword is optional and just serves to make the mehtod hiding declarative vs. implicit.  It in no way works like `override` so its hard to give an example htat makes it look like it does

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`new` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) will simply *hide* the base implementation, it will not override it. Not using the `new` modifier does the same thing, but implicitly.

When you define a variable as the `BaseClass`, it does not matter if you initialize it to a derived one. You can still only access the methods as they are defined in the base class.

```
BaseClass bcdc = new DerivedClass();

Console.WriteLine("bcdc __________________");
bcdc.Method1();
bcdc.Method2();
```

Again, using the `new` access modifier does not change the functionality, it only provides a clue to whoever looks at the class implementation to understand that the method is *supposed* to hide the base implementation.

Comment: You didn't understand me, I'm asking why when putting the new operator nothing changes

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It's perfectly accurate, as far as I can tell. I'll give it +1.

Comment: It might have been my initial misunderstanding as to what the question was. I originally thought OP wondered why using `new` did not override the base implementation.

Comment: There is also compiler warning generated when you hide a method without using the new keyword precisely because of this behavior.

Comment: @rae1 What does hide mean in `it only provides a clue to whoever looks at the class implementation to understand that the method is supposed to hide the base implementation.` ? it doesn't hide the baseclass' method, it's actually still called

Comment: @AymenDaoudi - According to the definitions found in the C# specification, the derived class member "hides" the base class member if it has the same name and signature and is not overriden. Thus, if you call the derived class, the "new" member is used. This is different from an "overriden" member as already explained by rae1.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi The base method does *not* get called regardless of whether you use the `new` modifier or not. Your statement "it doesn't hide the baseclass' method, it's actually still called" is not correct. There is actually no functional difference with or without the `new` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is exactly the difference between `virtual/override` and `new`!

- In the first case (`virtual/override`), the overridden method will be called, regardless of the type of variable you're invoking it from. This behavior has a name, it's called **polymorphism** and it's widely used in object oriented programming.
- In the second case (`new`), it depends! If the variable is of a type before the `new` method is defined, then the old method is called when you invoke from that variable. Otherwise, the newer method is called. This is called **method shadowing** (the methods share the same name but they are actually different and probably unrelated - that's why you get different behavior) and it's used when a base class has introduced a new method where your derived class already had that method. To tell C# that their relationship *is not* `virtual/override`, you use `new`. This generally is best avoided.

Comment: My problem is that adding new or not makes Method1 of the base class called, I can't find where is `Otherwise, the newer method is called` if the new keyword doesn't change things, then why it is here ?

Comment: `dc.Method1()` is supposed to print `Derived`, because the type of the `dc` variable is `DerivedClass`. `bcdc.Method1()` is supposed to print `Base`, because the type of the `bcdc` variable is `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), page 56:

> A declaration defines a name in the **declaration space to which the declaration belongs**. Except for overloaded members (§3.6), it is a compile-time error to have two or more declarations that introduce members with the same name in a declaration space.

When you declare your variable as a particular type, member lookups are done using that type's declaration space, with the exception of overriden members. Since you've not overriden the `Method1` member, the Base class' member is discovered and used.